# In modal logic, what is 'classical entailment'?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am familiar with the concepts of 'global entailment' and 'local entailment', and the distinction between them, but I am not familiar with 'classical entailment'. I also do not know a good textual reference for it, but I heard of it during a modal logic course lecture.

Similarly to how global entailment and local entailment are analogized to $∀x,P(x) → ∀x,Q(x)$ and $∀x(P(x) → Q(x))$, respectfully, what would 'classical entailment' be analogized to? How is classical entailment formally defined?

---

Update: I have met with my professor and apparently 'classical entailment' is defined as follows: where $p⊨_Cq$ notates that that $p$ classically entails $q$, the formal definition of classical entailment is

$p⊨_C q≔((p→q)=T)$

Comment: As far as I know, "classical entailment" just means $P \to Q$. This is as opposed to modified versions of entailment which involve a modal operator, for which see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_conditional

Comment: Where did you find that term?

Comment: @lemontree my professor used it in her modal logic course lecture.

Comment: In that case isn't it easiest to just ask her?

Comment: @lemontree I did during class, but i didnt really follow her response and she is generally unresponsive to emails

Comment: Maybe useful [Global vs. Local in Basic Modal Logic](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/m.derijke/wp-content/papercite-data/pdf/derijke-global-1999.pdf)

Comment: See [Entailment (aka: Logical consequence)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence): "a formula $A$ is a consequence within some formal system $\mathcal {FS}$ of a set of statements $\Gamma$: $\Gamma \models A$, if and only if there is no model $\mathfrak M$ in which all members of $\Gamma$  are true and $A$ is false."

Comment: Maybe the "analogy" withe the classical case is with (using formulas $A,B$ for simplicity) the two relations: (1) $A \vDash B$ (that reads: "for every model $\mathcal M$: if $\mathcal M \vDash A$, then $\mathcal M \vDash B$") and (2) if $\vDash A$, then $\vDash B$ (that reads: "if (for every model $\mathcal M: \mathcal M \vDash A$), then (for every model $\mathcal M: \mathcal M \vDash B)$").

Answer (score 1):

I wish to unfold the question a bit further for those interested in the concepts involved. I believe also it is a good practice not to leave the answer part blank as possible.

The parallelism drawn between local and global entailments in modal logic and the statements $\forall x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ and $\forall xP(x)\rightarrow\forall xQ(x)$ is appropriate. As noted by the OP, by "classical entailment", the notion of logical consequence that we are familiar with from the standard first-order predicate logic must be meant. These may be said to be some *extensional* images of *intensional* matters.

Let us move towards the definitions of local and global entailments reviewing the context.

In the possible worlds semantics for modal logic, *frames* act as domain discourse. A frame $\mathcal{F}$, denoted by a pair $(W, R)$, is a relational structure composed of a set of worlds $W$ and a binary accessibility relation $R$ on $W$. The relation $R$ specifies for each world $w\in W$ which worlds $w'$ in $W$ are relevant to (*viz*., accessible from) $w$. Thus, if the state of affairs represented by $w'$ does not differ from $w$ in the right respect, $wRw'$ does not hold.

A *model* for a basic language of modal language (notice that *not of a formula* as we are familiar with from model theory) consists of a frame $(W, R)$ and a valuation function $V$

$$\mathcal{M} = \langle W, R, V\rangle$$

$V$ assigns to each atomic proposition $p$ a set of possible worlds $V(p)\subseteq W$ at which $p$ is true. Given a set of atomic propositions, every model $\mathcal{M}$ is said to be *based on* a frame $\mathcal{F}$. Reciprocally, a frame $\mathcal{F}$ induces a class of models $\mathsf{Mod}$.

I ought to be remark that, studying these concepts, it is a worthwhile exercise to play with diagrams like the following (from the [Open Logic Project](https://openlogicproject.org/), which offers excellent sources for free):

[image]

We need to define what it is for a formula $\phi$ to be true at a world $w$ in a model $\mathcal{M}$. We denote *truth at a world* by

$$\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\phi$$

and define it in the inductive fashion we are familiar from model theory:

If $\phi$ is an atomic proposition $p$, then $\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash p\iff w\in V(p)$

If $\phi\equiv\neg\psi$, then $\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\phi\iff\mathcal{M}, w\nVdash\psi$

If $\phi\equiv(\psi_{1}\wedge\psi_{2})$, then $\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\phi\iff\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\psi_{1}\text{ and }\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\psi_{2}$

If $\phi\equiv(\psi_{1}\vee\psi_{2})$, then $\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\phi\iff\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\psi_{1}\text{ or }\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\psi_{2}$

If $\phi\equiv(\psi_{1}\rightarrow\psi_{2})$, then $\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\phi\iff\mathcal{M}, w\nVdash\psi_{1}\text{ or }\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\psi_{2}$

If $\phi\equiv\Box\psi$, then $\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\phi\iff\forall w′\in W,\;\mathcal{M}, w′\Vdash\psi\text{ such that }wRw′$

If $\phi\equiv\Diamond\psi$, then $\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\phi\iff\exists w′\in W,\;\mathcal{M}, w′\Vdash\psi\text{ such that }wRw′$

Now, we can define what it is to be true in a model $\mathcal{M}$ for a formula $\phi$. We denote *truth in a model* by

$$\mathcal{M}\Vdash\phi$$

and define it as

$$\mathcal{M}\Vdash\phi\iff\forall w\in W,\;\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\phi$$

Suppose we have a class of models $\mathsf{Mod}=\{\mathcal{M}_{1}, \mathcal{M}_{2},\ldots\}$. We can define validity of a formula $\phi$ with respect to $\mathsf{Mod}$ as

$$\phi\text{ is valid in }\mathsf{Mod}\iff\forall\mathcal{M}\in\mathsf{Mod},\; \mathcal{M}\Vdash\phi$$

If $\phi$ is valid in $\mathsf{Mod}$, we denote this by $\mathsf{Mod}\vDash\phi$. We write only $\vDash\phi$ to indicate that $\phi$ is valid in the class of all models. We can also define validity of a formula $\phi$ in a frame $\mathcal{F}$. We denote this by $\mathcal{F}\vDash\phi$ and define it as truth in all the models $\mathcal{M}$ in the class of models $\mathsf{Mod}$ based on (*viz*., induced by) $\mathcal{F}$ and denote it by $\mathsf{Mod}\vDash\phi$.

So far, we have recorded the definitions of fundamental notions. Having grasped them, we can talk about local and global entailments (logical consequences). The conceptions fork into two groups: One is grounded in models, the other one in frames. First, we shall take up the definitions by models, thereafter those by frames.

For a model $\mathcal{M}$ and a set of formulas $\Gamma\cup\{\phi\}$, we say that $\Gamma$ *locally entails* $\phi$ in $\mathcal{M}$, or $\phi$ is a *local semantic
consequence of* $\Gamma$ in $\mathcal{M}$, when we have for any $w\in W$ (of $\mathcal{M}$)

$$\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\Gamma\implies\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\phi$$

We say that $\Gamma$ *globally entails* $\phi$ in $\mathcal{M}$, or $\phi$ is a *global semantic consequence* of $\Gamma$ in $\mathcal{M}$, when we have

$$\mathcal{M}\Vdash\Gamma\implies\mathcal{M}\Vdash\phi$$

Notice that, for local entailment, we employ the notion of truth at a world, and for global entailment, the notion of truth in a model. We denote these conceptions of local and global entailments by $\Gamma\vDash^{l}_{\mathcal{M}}\phi$ and $\Gamma\vDash^{g}_{\mathcal{M}}\phi$, respectively; usually the superscript $l$ is dropped.

Alternatively, the local and global entailments can be defined with respect to frames. Given a class of frames $\mathsf{F}$, for any $\mathcal{F}\in\mathsf{FR}$ and for any model $\mathcal{M}$ based on $\mathcal{F}$, we say that $\Gamma$ *locally entails* $\phi$ in $\mathcal{M}$, or $\phi$ is a *local semantic consequence of* $\Gamma$, when we have for any $w\in W$ (of $\mathcal{M}$)

$$\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\Gamma\implies\mathcal{M}, w\Vdash\phi$$

We say that $\Gamma$ *globally entails* $\phi$ in $\mathcal{M}$, or $\phi$ is a *global semantic consequence* of $\Gamma$, when we have

$$\mathcal{M}\Vdash\Gamma\implies\mathcal{M}\Vdash\phi$$

In this case, we denote by $\Gamma\vDash^{l}_{\mathsf{F}}\phi$ and $\Gamma\vDash^{g}_{\mathsf{F}}\phi$, respectively. The superscript $l$ is usually dropped also here.